# Jenkins Build Flow Plugin sequentially chain multiple jobs in parallel

Tags: jenkins, groovy, build, parallel-processing, series

I'm attempting to replicate this functionality from the Build Flow Plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin:

```
parallel (
    {
        build("job1")
        build("job2")
    },
    {
        build("job5")
        build("job6")
    }
)
```

I have the following DSL job:

```
subjob = "test"
subjob2 = "test2"
series1 = []
series2 = []
subjob = []

["job1","job2"].each{ parameter ->
  series1.add({build( subjob, param: parameter )})
}

["job5","job6"].each{ parameter2 ->
  series2.add({build( subjob2, param: parameter2)})
}

subjob.add(series1)
subjob.add(series2)

parallel( subjob )
```

My goal is to run one set of jobs 1&2 in series and another set of jobs 5&6 in series, but to run both sets of jobs in parallel. i.e. Job 1 and 5 kick off at the same time, then when job 1 finishes job 2 start and when job 5 finishes job 6 starts.

However, I've tried a number of variations on the above code, but different errors each time.  The above code gives the following:

```
ERROR: Failed to run DSL Script
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '[Script1$_run_closure1$_closure3@3c52c84, Script1$_run_closure1$_closure3@56789ba0]' with class 'java.util.ArrayList' to class 'groovy.lang.Closure' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: failed to invoke constructor: public groovy.lang.Closure(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object) with arguments: [Script1$_run_closure1$_closure3@3c52c84, Script1$_run_closure1$_closure3@56789ba0] reason: java.lang.InstantiationException
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parallel step / function expects a list of closures, e.g. a list of code blocks. What you are giving it is a list of list with closures, and naturally you can't cast that to a closure, hence the error:

```
Cannot cast object '...' with class 'java.util.ArrayList' to class 'groovy.lang.Closure'
```

What you need to do is to wrap the serial jobs in a closure:

```
subjob = "test"
subjob2 = "test2"
series1 = []
series2 = []
subTasks = []

["job1","job2"].each{ parameter ->
  series1.add({build( subjob, param: parameter )})
}

["job5","job6"].each{ parameter2 ->
  series2.add({build( subjob2, param: parameter2)})
}

subTasks.add({
  series1.each{it()}
})
subTasks.add({
  series2.each{it()}
})

parallel( subTasks )
```

An explanation of what I do:

```
subTasks.add({
  series1.each{it()}
})
```

First we add a new closure to the list `subTasks`, this closure takes each element in the list and executes it (`it()`).

Comment: Thanks, I understand the theory now, but I'm getting the following when runnnig your code: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method call() on null object

Comment: Wops, my bad, it should be `series1.each{it()}`, e.g. brackets instead of parentheses. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Looking better ;), now getting 
`java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.cloudbees.plugins.flow.FlowDelegate.build() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.util.ArrayList) values: [[param:job1], [Script1$_run_closure3@5bc92f8c, Script1$_run_closure4@3a163c10]]
Possible solutions: build(java.lang.String), build(java.util.Map, java.lang.String), fail(), find(), getBuild(), wait()`

Comment: Yep, another bug, you hade used the variable `subjob` twice, once for the name of the first job (at the first line) and for storing the subjobs at line five. I've updated the example in the answer by renaming the second variable to subTasks

Comment: sorted! great example now!